# Cannot bind port 111 on docker on WSL2 on windows, but port is (apparently?) currently free

Tags: docker, port, host, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-networking

## Setup

I have this setup:

- `Windows 10 pro` with `WSL2` with an `Ubuntu 20.04` inside.
- Inside the Ubuntu, I have a running `docker engine` that has been working perfectly for over during months, exposing multiple ranges of ports with dozens of images and containers. All perfect.

## NFS version 3 and port 111

Today I was playing with an NFS server that must be run on version 3. Port `111` is required in addition to port `2049`. The original test was with the image `erichough/nfs-server`.

I narrowed down to problem to this **minimum failing example:**

If I do this:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 111:111 alpine
```

I get this:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint hardcore_kilby (9aa7466f1771c9b5926a00eede289fc1084a12ee09ea2f3deee917c4734034c9): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:111: bind: address already in use.
```

[image: docker on port 111 fails]

This suggests that port `111` is used in the host.

To discard it's not something related to the [well-known ports range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports) I bound a different port: `112` instead of `111`, and it succeeded:

[image: docker on port 112 works]

Therefore I thought there's a process listening on port `111`.

## Nobody on port 111?

This [answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23718720/1315009) says that *Resource monitor* can do the job of finding "what process is blocking a port". I launched it, sorted the listing of "Listening ports" by "Port" and....

**Oh surprise!!!** there's nobody listening on port `111`!

[image: Port 111 is not used]

## Is RPC blocking the port?

The [answer below from @Drixter](https://serverfault.com/a/1062979/253400) suggests `netstat -tapneu` to see if the port `111` is blocked by RPC.

### On the linux side

`netstat -tapneu` only works on the linux side of the WSL and reports **no** port `111` being used.

### On the windows side

On the windows side of the WSL (for example via git-bash) the `-u` option does not exist, the `-e` option collapses the results to statistics, and the `-p`requires an extra parameter. So I narrowed down to `netstat -tan` and also `netstat -n`.

And **none** of those reports port `111`.

## Going deeper

My computer has a fixed IP address in a LAN at `192.168.3.xx`. If I specify the IP for the `-p` option, I can see that port `111` is only used on loopback: `127.0.0.1` (also in the rest of `lo` addresses like `127.0.0.2`, `127.0.0.3`, etc) but, instead, the port is **free** on the LAN address:

[image: See IP address failing]

## Why?

- Why is this happening?
- In my case the IP is static. Should I only expose `111` on the docker container to the host on the LAN address and can never be done in the `localhost` address?
- Can it be that the port `111` is used but "not detectable"?
- Can I see if I do have this RPC thing and its status on the windows side?

Comment: Linux, in default settings, only allows root to listen on a well known port. Port 111 is a well known port, port 112 is not. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers . Either use root to start a service which is listening on a well known port, adjust the Linux default settings or use another port.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that RPC is not using port 111?

```
netstat -tapneu | grep 111
```

Comment: Edited the question to incorporate this information. No port `111` reported by netstat, neither in the linux side of the WSL, neither in the windows side of the WSL.

Comment: Maybe you need to force to expose 111 from proper 127.0.0.x, I do not know docker, but "listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:111: bind: address already in use" is trying to bind across all interfaces, and one IP is occupied with this port and becuase of this fail.

Comment: As exposed in my latest edition of the question, I already tried `127.0.0.1` as well as other few in the local range, like `127.0.0.2`, `.3`, `.4`... So Definitively "someone" is blocking port `111` on the `lo` interface. As exposed in the latest edit, address `192.168.3.x` has port `111` free. Half of the problem disappears as I can now work on the LAN IP and continue -I think; going to test now- But still the question is "who is locking `111` in `lo` and why?

Comment: Does the telnet work to 111? if something is using that port then connection should be established, then try to check netstat, connection should appear. Could be that Windows is blocking this by any reason, but here I'm guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious.

So, it's saying "port in use", what is the output of the following powershell command?

```
Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 111).OwningProcess | Format-List *
```

This should produce a list of processes that are listening on that port in Windows. I'm just curious if it would give the same information as the resource monitor.

If there is no output from the above powershell, then

```
 sudo ss -tulpn | grep 111
```

run in WSL should give the pid of anything listening on that port in the linux subsystem.

These should at least conclusively tell you whether its vanilla port collision, or if there's nothing actually listening on that port and something weirder is going on.

Comment: The subpart of the command `Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 111` fails with no `MSFT_NetTCPConnection` objects found, so the rest of the command fails. The `sudo ss -tulpn | grep 111` command gives an empty output. 2 yrs later, the docker run as `docker run -it --rm -p 111:111 alpine` still respondes `listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:111: bind: address already in use.` so the question is still active.